# Drawing a wordnet with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to use TikZ to draw a wordnet like this

[image]

but I really don't know what to start with. Can anybody help me with drawing this graph?
Unfortunately, I don't have enough time to read books about TikZ. It's a part of my hometask for today :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: These examples should give you enough starting points. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/

Answer (score 13):

A possibility using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[entity
  [inanimate-object
    [natural-object
      [geological-formation
        [natural-elevation [hill], tikz={
           \foreach \nodenam/\nodelabel in {!ul/0.000113,!u/0.000189}
             \node[anchor=east,xshift=-10pt] at (\nodenam.west) {$\nodelabel$};                              
            }
        ] 
        [shore [coast], tikz={
            \foreach \nodename/\nodelabel in {!ul/0.0000216,!u/0.0000836,!uu/0.00176,!uuu/0.0163,!uuuu/0.167,!ur/0.365}
                \node[anchor=west,xshift=10pt] at (\nodename.east) {$\nodelabel$};
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

### A tree-based solution

One possible solution to this is to `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in combination with `qtree` and `tikz-qtree`. The latter two will allow you to draw tree structures like the tree that you're after, and the `positioning` library will allow you to define nodes in terms of other nodes in order to place the numbers relative to the words.

Here is an MWE for such a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree
[.\node(entity){entity};
    [.\node(inanimate){inanimate object};
        [.\node(natural){natural object};
            [.\node(geological){geological formation};
                [.\node(naturalelev){natural elevation};
                    [.\node(hill){hill}; ]
                ]
                [.\node(shore){shore};
                    [.\node(coast){coast}; ]
                ] ] ] ] ]
\node [base right=2cm of entity] (1) {0.395} ;
\node [base left=2.5cm of entity] (align) {};
\node [below=0.6cm of 1] (2) {0.167};
\node [below=0.6cm of 2] (3) {0.0163};
\node [below=0.55cm of 3] (4) {0.00176};
\node [below=0.6cm of 4] (5) {0.0000836};
\node [below=0.5cm of 5] (6) {0.0000216};
\node [below=3.8cm of align] (7) {0.000113};
\node [below=.5cm of 7] (8) {0.0000189};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The disadvantage to this solution is that you have to place the additionally-defined nodes manually. Someone can probably think of a more elegant solution than I can, which would be particularly nice if you have to make many of these diagrams. Nonetheless, this solution at least seems to provide what you're after in this case.

---

### A matrix-based solution

Another solution that avoids the problem noted directly above: namely, the problem of having to define the nodes manually each time you have to draw one of these diagrams (or each time you resize one of them) is to `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}`. Placing all of the information inside the rows and columns of a matrix allows one to avoid the issue of having to space the information manually using the `\node` command, since this is automatically done in virtue of the information being stored in the rows and columns of a matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=1.5em,
column sep=0.3em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{
& & entity & & 0.395 \\ 
& & inanimate object & & 0.167 \\ 
& & natural object & & 0.0163 \\ 
& & geological formation & & 0.00176 \\ 
0.000113 & natural elevation & & shore & 0.0000836 \\ 
0.0000189 & hill & & coast & 0.0000216 \\ 
};

\path[-]    (m-1-3) edge (m-2-3)
            (m-2-3) edge (m-3-3)
            (m-3-3) edge (m-4-3)
            (m-4-3) edge (m-5-2)
            (m-5-2) edge (m-6-2)
            (m-4-3) edge (m-5-4)
            (m-5-4) edge (m-6-4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]